# Fill Dropdown from Selected Item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What I am trying to make is a workbook that users can select from a dropdown of a group of items (Sheet1, Column A) and then Row B lookup that selected item in sheet "Dataset" and return that value with integers that go from `0` to the corresponding stock quantity total in (Sheet "Dataset" column C)

[here is a Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DchLLSY7pWnwGX521fdaahvW7Ux8eV_taTTkR-VLlZw/edit?usp=sharing)

I got some awesome code from [@iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) that will fill the dropdowns from the corresponding stock quantity
[see his code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946560/11921951) that I have somewhat implemented [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WNqi01kV42accDb5METY49s36xU4ORyw3eMdX46AOAk/edit?usp=sharing) using a query formula to lookup the group stock quantities. I'm not sure how to make this happen across two sheets though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Extending the code that [@iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946560/11921951), you can specify the Sheets from which to get the data from and use an onEdit() trigger to automatically change the dropdown when the cell is edited.*

#### Code:

Attach this to the Sample Spreadsheet you provided:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get the spreadsheet bound to this script
  var dataSetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dataset"); // Get the sheet called "Working with script" (change if necessary)
  var fillSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  
  // Get the different values in column C (stock quantities):
  var firstRow = 3;
  var firstCol = 3;
  var numRows = dataSetSheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var stockQuantities = dataSetSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows).getValues();
  var stockNames = dataSetSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol - 1, numRows).getValues();
  
  // Iterate through all values in column:
  for (var i = 0; i < stockQuantities.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(stockNames);
    Logger.log(stockQuantities);
    var stockQuantity = stockQuantities[i][0];
    var values = [];
    // Create the different options for the dropdown based on the value in column C:
    
    if (stockNames[i] == e.value) {
      for (var j = 0; j <= stockQuantity; j++) {
        values.push(j);
      }   
      // Create the data validation:
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values).build();
      // Add the data validation to the corresponding cell in column B:
      fillSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 2).clear();
      var dropdownCell = fillSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 2).setDataValidation(rule);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Something to note:

I have put this as an `onEdit()` function because `SpreadsheetApp` is called in [**Read Only mode**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) when inside a custom function and so no `set*()` methods can be called. This includes `setDataValidation()`.

As per the Documentation, the Spreadsheet service is supported, however under 'Notes' it reads:

> Read only (can use most `get*()` methods, but not `set*()`).
> Cannot open other spreadsheets (`SpreadsheetApp.openById()` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`).

#### References:

- [Stack Overflow - Dropdown auto generating a range based on a total](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946560/11921951)
- [Google Apps Script - `Range.clear()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear)
- [Google Apps Script - Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Google Apps Script - Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced)

Comment: hey i also have some items that do not require a dropdown to select item type (column A)

Would it be possible for another script to run and update these dropdowns (Column B)?