# Dropdown fill from dataset making range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

TLDR: script to fill dropdown creating integers that go from 0 to the corresponding Stock Quantity from dataset.

What I am trying to make is a workbook that users can select from a dropdown of a group of items (Sheet1, Column A) and then Row B lookup that selected item in sheet "Dataset" and return that value with integers that go from `0` to the corresponding stock quantity total in (Sheet "Dataset" column C)

[here is a Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDobuHJIk4gze-ZNOoakPYlMkOB2UVOYX9jWwcqTyR4/edit?usp=sharing)

this is all working thanks to [@iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) and [@Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11551468/rafa-guillermo)

but a also have items that do not require users to select the item from a dropdown.

I have tried to write some code (line 39 down) but i am stuck.

Any help would be very appreciated.

```
    function generateDropdowns() {

//sets all the dropdowns from items non selected

  // Get the different values in column C (stock quantities):
  var firstRow = 3;
  var firstCol = 3;
  var numRows = dataSetSheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numRowsfill = fillSheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1; 
  var stockQuantities = dataSetSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows).getValues();
  var stockNames = dataSetSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol - 1, numRows).getValues();
  var itemName = fillSheet.getRange(3, 1, numRowsfill).getValues();

  // Iterate through all values in volumn:
  for (var i = 0; i < stockQuantities.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(stockNames);
    Logger.log(stockQuantities);
    var stockQuantity = stockQuantities[i][0];
    var values = [];

    // Create the different options for the dropdown based on the value in column C:
    if (stockNames[i] == itemName[i]) {
      for (var j = 0; j <= stockQuantity; j++) {
        values.push(j);
      } 
          // Create the data validation:
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values).build();
    // Add the data validation to the corresponding cell in column B:
    var dropdownCell = fillSheet.getRange(i + firstRow, 2).setDataValidation(rule);

   }    
  }
}
```

Past posts
[Dropdown auto generating a range based on a total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59869138/dropdown-auto-generating-a-range-based-on-a-total)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959984/fill-dropdown-from-selected-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Generating dropdown from edited cell:

In the sample provided by [@Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11551468/rafa-guillermo), items that are simply written, and not selected from a dropdown, follow the same workflow than items selected from a dropdown. The script just looks at which value the edited cell has, disregarding whether it was selected from a dropdown or not. You can notice this if you write a value in column A (from `Sheet 1`): the corresponding dropdown in column B will show up.

So the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59966021/10612011) already does what you say you want to accomplish.

#### Generating all dropdowns:

If what you want to do instead is automatically generating all the dropdowns from the values in `Sheet 1`, and not only the one corresponding to the cell that was edited, you can do this instead (check inline comments):

```js
function generateDropdowns() {
  var firstRow = 3;
  var firstCol = 3;
  var numRows = dataSetSheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numRowsfill = fillSheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1; 
  var stockQuantities = dataSetSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows).getValues().map(function(quantity) {
    return quantity[0]; // 1-D array of stock quantities
  });
  var stockNames = dataSetSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol - 1, numRows).getValues().map(function(stockName) {
    return stockName[0]; // 1-D array of stock names
  });
  var itemNames = fillSheet.getRange(3, 1, numRowsfill).getValues().map(function(itemName) {
    return itemName[0]; // 1-D array of items
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) { // Iterate through all items in Sheet 1
    if (stockNames.indexOf(itemNames[i]) !== -1) { // Check if item shows up in stock names
      var stockQuantity = stockQuantities[stockNames.indexOf(itemNames[i])]; // Get the stock quantity corresponding to this item
      var values = [];
      for (var j = 0; j <= stockQuantity; j++) {
        values.push(j); // Generate possible values for dropdown
      }
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values).build();
      var dropdownCell = fillSheet.getRange(i + firstRow, 2).setDataValidation(rule);      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks again for your assistance and knowledge code works great